# Python: Arguments to sorting function

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort a python list of strings. I know that I can use the method sorted and set the attribute key to be a function that implements the behavior I need to sort the elements of the dictionary on. My problem is that this method needs an argument.

UPDATE:
I want the method to generalize to multiple arguments.

Example: 
I want to sort a list of strings based on their priorities in 2 dictionaries . So I need to use those priority dictionaries in sorting the list.

I want something like:

```
sorted(myList, key=sortingAlgorithm(priorityDictionary1, priorityDictionary2), reverse=True)
```

This can be done if I set the priority dictionaries as global variables and then I will not need to have it as an argument to the sorting algorithm. But, I want to be able to do it without global variables.

If this is not possible, can you please recommend the pythonic way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that functions can return functions, right?

Comment: What is `sortingAlgorithm()` in your code ? The `sorted()` function has its own sorting algorithm, what it needs is instructions where each item should go, compared to the others. `Key=` needs to be "*a function which takes a list item, and returns a number/string/sortable value*".  And as the answers come in, there are many approaches to that - but none of them involve passing a sorting algorithm to sort...

Comment: Are both values combined or is the second a tie-breaker?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham both values are combined

Comment: @Hossam, so `dict1[x] + dict2[x]` or `dict2[dict1[x]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `key=priorityDictionary.get`

`get` is a method on a dictionary that takes a key and returns a value, if one is found.

Edit: The above solution applies to a case of a single `dict`. Here is a generalization where values of `priorityDict2` are keys for `priorityDict1`.

And, as Padriac Cunningham points out, you can use a `lambda` to sort using nested dicts:

```
output = sorted(myList, key=lambda element: priorityDict1[priorityDict2[element]])
```

Comment: Oooh, point -- I was thinking we needed a comparator, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you please check my update?

Comment: @Hossam do you want a lexicographic sort on `tuples` in this case?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko No, I want to use the values from both dictionaries and incorporate them in a function that returns the value that should be used for sorting.

Comment: Right, but there are many ways of doing so. For instance, you can take the minimal rank, the maximal rank, or you can compare the first position first, the second position second, etc.

Comment: Actually it is nested. So something like priorityDict1[priorityDict2[element]]

Comment: In line with @Isongen74's response, you can use a `key=lambda element: priorityDict1[priorityDict2[element]]`. I would suggest that you add this explicitly to you question to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure.

```
def something(foo):
  def somethingsomething(bar):
    return foo(bar)
  return somethingsomething

baz = something(len)
print baz('quux')
```

Answer (score 1):

Code -

```
priorities = {'xyz' : 1, 'cde' : 3, 'abc' : 4, 'pqr' : 2}

arr = ['abc', 'cde', 'pqr', 'xyz', 'cde', 'abc']

arr.sort(key = lambda s : priorities[s])

print(arr)
```

Output -

```
['xyz', 'pqr', 'cde', 'cde', 'abc', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

Some slightly more standalone examples:

```
stringList = ["A1", "B3", "C2", "D4"]
priorityDict = {"A1": 1, "B3": 3, "C2": 2, "D4": 4}

# Reference an accessor function
print sorted(stringList, key=priorityDict.get)

# Provide a lambda function (with "free" closure)
print sorted(stringList, key=lambda x: priorityDict[x])

# Provide a normal function (helper definition needs scope visibility 
# on priority dict, but doesn't have to be global - you can define 
# functions in the scope of other functions a little like lambdas)
def myKey(x):
    return priorityDict[x]

print sorted(stringList, key=myKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the value from one dict as the key to the next you need a function or a lambda:

```
l = ["foo", "Foo", "Bar", "bar", "foobar", "Foobar"]

d1 = {"f": 1, "F": 0, "b": 1, "B": 0}
d2 = {1: 10, 0: 20}
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: d2[d1[x[0]]]))
```

If a key may not exist you can still use get:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: d2.get(d1.get(x[0], {}), some_default))
```

Just make sure some_default makes sense and can be compared to the other values.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sortingAlgorithm(primaryDictionary):
  def __cmp__(a, b):
    pass # do something with a, b, and primaryDictionary here
  return __cmp__
```